# database changed outside of DataSet: duplicate key exception

Tags: database, exception, dataset, sql-update, dataadapter

I'm using a strongly typed DataSet and I fill all Tables of the DataSet at the beginning of the program. I have one table that can be changed by multiple users. Sometimes it happens that this table is changed outside of the dataSet, so that the user does not have the newest version of the table and gets an Exception when trying to insert the same row.

my procedure:
When a user wants to insert a new row I check the dataset for the existence of the row and only insert the row if it is not already there. But in the meantime (between filling and checking) it happens that another user inserts the same row into the database. So I get the SQLException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint (error 2627).
How can I avoid this?

Thats how I check if the row is already part of database:

```
customersTableAdapter custAdapter = new customersTableAdapter();
AzureDataSet.customersRow custRow= azureDataSet.customers.FindBycustID(hash); 
if(custRow==null)
{    
    try
    {      
        custRow= azureDataSet.customers.NewcustomersRow();
        custRow.custID = hash;

        azureDataSetcustomers.AddcustomersRow(custRow);               
        retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
        {
            customersTableAdapter.Update(azureDataSet.customers);
        });
    }
    catch
    {
       //check for error 2627??
    }
}
return custRow.custID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that TableAdapters do not provide a data synchronisation.
I wrote a stored procedure to insert the data and checked in the stored procedure if the value is already there.
I also catched a duplicate key exception which migth still occur, because of the delay between the check and the insert operation.